# Alternative representations for $\int_1^e e^{e^{t W_{-1}\left(\frac{-\ln(t)}{t}\right)}}dt$ and $\int_{e^{-e}}^{e^{\frac1e}}e^{t+W_0(-\ln(t))}dt$?

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, lambert-w

Some time ago I posted an answer in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4438079/695196). The original question was about evaluating
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^x}{^{2n}x} \mathrm{d}x
$$
where $^{2n}x$ is the power tower of height $2n$. In Knuth arrow notation $^{2n}x = x \mathbin{\uparrow}\mathbin{\uparrow} 2n$.

In my answer, I posted an integral representation of the limiting value, given by
$$
e^{1+e^{-e}}-1 - \int_{1}^{e} e^{ e^{y W_{-1}\left( \frac{-\ln(y)}{y}\right)}} 
 \mathrm{d}y+\int_{e^{-e}}^{e^{\frac1e}} e^{x +W_0\left( -\ln(x)\right)}  \mathrm{d}x 
$$

---

Afterward, I found that in some cases the Lambert-W function in an integral can lead to nice simplifications like in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1283967/lambert-w-function-integral), [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2907761/integrating-a-function-involving-lambert-w?noredirect=1), or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/926073/integration-of-lambert-w-function?noredirect=1) example.  I tried replicating some of the ideas used in these questions but mostly ended up with integrals involving things like $e^{e^u}$ which didn't seem any more straightforward.

Nevertheless, just because I couldn't seem to find some interesting alternate representations for the integral doesn't mean they don't exist. So my question is

> Are there some other interesting representations for $e^{1+e^{-e}}-1 - \int_{1}^{e} e^{ e^{y W_{-1}\left( \frac{-\ln(y)}{y}\right)}} 
>  \mathrm{d}y+\int_{e^{-e}}^{e^{\frac1e}} e^{x +W_0\left( -\ln(x)\right)}  \mathrm{d}x $? Either in integral, infinte sum or special function form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let’s do the
$$\int_{e^{-e}}^{\sqrt[e]e} e^{x+\text W(-\ln(x))}dx $$
part:

$$\int_{e^{-e}}^{\sqrt[e]e} e^{x+\text W(-\ln(x))}dx = -\int_e^{-\frac1e} \frac{e^{e^{-x}} e^{-x} x}{\text W(x)}dx =\int_{-\frac1e}^e\frac{x}{\text W(x)}\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{e^{-x(m+1)}}{m!}dx$$

which [is valid](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integral+%281%2F6+e%5E%28-4+x%29+%281+%2B+3+e%5Ex+%2B+6+e%5E%282+x%29+%2B+6+e%5E%283+x%29%29%29+x%2Flambertw%28x%29+from+-1%2Fe+to+e). Integration by parts on $\int xf(x) dx$ would complicate the problem, so another sum is okay:

$$\int_{-\frac1e}^e\frac{x}{\text W(x)}\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{e^{-x(m+1)}}{m!}dx= \int_{-\frac1e}^e\frac{x}{\text W(x)}\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac1{m!}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-x(m+1))^n}{n!} dx$$

The last series expansion is also valid with this [**demo**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integral+exp%28lambertw%28x%29%29+Sum%5BSum%5B%28-%28x+%28m+%2B+1%29%29%29%5En%2Fn%21%2C+%7Bn%2C+0%2C+130%7D%5D%2Fm%21%2C%7Bm%2C0%2C30%7D%5D+from+-1%2Fe+to+e), so:

$$\int_{-\frac1e}^e\frac{x}{\text W(x)}\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac1{m!}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-x(m+1))^n}{n!} dx=\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac1{m!}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-(m+1))^n}{n!} \int_{-\frac1e}^e\frac{x^{n+1}}{\text W(x)} dx $$

A goal is to use [this formula](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integral++x%5Ep%2Flambertw%28x%29)

If one is careful with the summation bounds, one finds this [**double sum of an En function**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Sum%5B1%2Fm%21+Sum%5B%28-%28m%2B1%29%29%5En%2Fn%21%28+%28e%5E%282+%2B+n%29+-+En%28-n%2C+-2+-+n%29%29%2F%282+%2B+n%29-%28%28-1%29%5E%281+%2B+n%29+%28e%5E%28-2+-+n%29+-+En%28-n%2C+2+%2B+n%29%29%29%2F%282+%2B+n%29%29%2C%7Bn%2C0%2C150%7D%5D%2C%7Bm%2C0%2C50%7D%5D) which can be rewritten in terms of incomplete gamma functions.

Therefore, when $\sum\limits_{m,n\ge0}=\sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty$. Note the [En function](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=En%28n%2Cx%29) and the [Ei function](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Ei+function):

$$\int_{e^{-e}}^{\sqrt[e]e} e^{x+\text W(-\ln(x))}dx =2\text{Ei}(1)-\text{Ei}\left(\sqrt[e]e\right)-\text{Ei}\left(e^{-e}\right)+e^{\sqrt[e]e-1}-e^{e^{-e}-1}-\sum_{m,n\ge0}\frac{(m+1)^n}{(n+2)m!n!}\left(\text E_{-n}(n+2)+(-1)^n\text E_{-n}(-(n+2))\right)$$

Is it possible to simplify this double sum?

For the second part,

$$\int _1^e e^{e^{x\text W_{-1}\left(-\frac{\ln(x)}x\right)}}dx=\int_{-\frac1e}^0 \frac{e^{e^{ \frac{\text W(x)\text W_{-1}(x)}x}}}{x^2}\left(\text W(x)+\frac1{\text W(x)+1}-1\right)dx$$

which looks much harder than the first integral above